# Declaring and Instantiating inside a class block

Tags: java, object, block

In the Class Block:

Instead of making an Object (In this case a simple String) like this:

```
public String one = "Hello!";
```

I wanted to do it like this:

```
String one;
one = "Hello!";
```

but *compiler* throws:

```
error: <identifier> expected
```

Why? Why the second has to be within a method?

Comment: Is it compile time error or runtime ? If runtime then paste stack trace.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani It's compile-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more than likely that

```
one = "Hello!"
```

is located in the class block. This statement must be appear inside a code block — that is; a method, constructor or static initializer. E.g.:

```
void myMethod() {
    String one;
    one = "Hello!";
}
```

Non declarative statements cannot appear in the class block.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this should be in a constructor of some sort... either way, you must place it inside of a method or constructor (or other code block). This is simply one of the rules of the Java syntax.

```
public String one;

public MyClass() {
    one = "hello";
}
```

If you made the field `static`, you could have

```
public static String one;

static {
    one = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `one = "Hello!";` line needs to be inside a method.